# Сервлет отрабатывает 2 или более раз

Tags: java, servlet

Сайт написан на чистых сервлетах, никаких фреймворков не используется. При открытии любой страницы сервлет этой страницы отрабатывает 2 или более раз.

В чем причина?

---

Маппинг сервлетов в аннотациях. Например, для главной страницы:

**Index.java**

```
@WebServlet(name = "index", urlPatterns = {"/index.html"})
public class Index extends AbstractServlet {

    protected static char[] page;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doResponse(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doResponse(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void preparePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        ... creating page from template ...

        setPage(stringBuilder.toString().toCharArray());
    }
}
```

---

**AbstractServlet.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected char[] getPage() throws ServletException, IOException {
        return (char[]) this.getClass().getField("page").get(this.getClass());
    }

    protected void setPage(char[] page) {
        this.getClass().getField("page").set(this.getClass(), page);
    }

    protected void doResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        if (this.getPage() == null) {
            this.preparePage(request, response);
        }

        pw.write(this.getPage());
    }

    protected abstract void preparePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException;
}
```

---

**Скриншот заголовков первого запроса**

[image: Chrome Screenshot 1]

---

**Скриншот заголовков второго запроса**

[image: Chrome Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Клиент указал в сообщении `referrer: http://localhost/index.php`, это означает что первый запрос инициировал второй (это аутентификация, либо переадресация, или иная ошибка).

Теперь видно, что браузер создает второй запрос на `/index.html`.
Но в ответе сервера нет заголовка `Redirect /index.html` и код ответа 200.
Значит в теле ответа есть текст:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=/index.html">
```

Либо иные ссылки на `/index.html`. И судя по `Accept` идет запрос картинки.

Если нет, приложите к вопросу "тело" первого сообщения сервера, разгадка в нем.

А сервлет вполне нормально обрабатывает два разных запроса:

- GET(http://localhost/)
- GET(http://localhost/index.html)